# user identity certificate

Tags: authentication, certificates, x.509

I want to create a new scheme for user identification, like X.509 certificates, but not X.509. Is it possible to use this new certificate over the existing Internet? and if yes, what are basic attributes that must be retained OR can be omitted?

Comment: Why not use X.509? What doesn't it do that you need? And/or what does it do that you can't live with?

Answer (score 5):

1. You keep using that word identification. I do not think it means what you think it does.
2. The Internet moves bits, it does't care what those bits are. Obviously third party servers won't respect non-standard certificates, because, you know, "standard".
3. Up to you what attributes you include since you are designing your own PKI.
4. Don't design your own PKI.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers:

**Is it Technically Possible?**

Yep.  All things are technically possible, given enough time, money and ingenuity.  You can create a new cryptographically linked model for identification, create new standards for how the identified entity is described, create a new back end to provide for issuing, revoking and verifying the proof of identity and find a new way of transferring the data.

Chances are, you'll want some form of assymmetric keying, since you need a cryptographic way of figuring out which individual entity you are identifying, and symmetric keys are painful for this.  And you'll want a LOT of time and manpower - reinventing PKI is not easy.

The hardest challenges I see would be trying to get this into SSL, but you could always do a server auth SSL/HTTPS session and then put your new identification scheme into the application payload above it - for example in an HTTP POST.  The standards for the application layer of networking are open ended enough that this can easily be done.

**Is it a Good Idea?**

No.  Absolutely not.

The thing about an identification scheme is it works best if everyone agrees.  The reasons for the standards of X509 certificates, SSL client authentication, various types of digital signatures and other ways of proving custody of private keys is that it makes it MUCH easier to implement across vendor products, network gear, operating systems and other components.  That said, it's still not easy to wire this stuff up - even with all these standards big organizations spend a LOT of money each year getting their infrastructures able to do identification of both users and equipment.

A common model for this situation is the story of the "cost of the first fax machine" - the first fax machine was extremely expensive, and totally useless.  Being the very first machine, it no other place to send a fax, so it was essentially a brick that did nothing.  The second fax machine gave tremendous value to the first fax machine.  But the time many, many fax machines were in existence, the cost of each additional fax machine was trivial compared to the vast power of being able to send faxes all over the place.

The same thing goes here - if you roll your own, you will have to create at least two points - the sender and the receiver and run this entirely yourself.  Creating a new model for PKI is going to be many manyears of effort and more manyears of integration and support of a custom built model.

Unless you are a nation state, I don't advise it.

Wait... even if you are a nation state, I don't advise it.

**Alternate**

The PKI model is pretty modular.  There's all sorts of creative ways to describe the entity you want to identify.  And different ways to write your security policy to handle revocation and verification.  There's all sorts of open source products that will let you customize a CA, customize the verification tools, and distribute revocation information - and if you are clever enough, you can do it while not violating the basic standards for this.

There's both XML and ASN.1 ways of describing the cryptographic artifacts and connecting it to information and actions for users and non-human entities.

If the path to a standards compliant solution isn't clear, this is a great place to ask additional questions.